# Does this hard magic system have well-defined limits? What sounds exaggerated or vague about it?

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems

**CONDITIONS/REQUIREMENTS**

1. *Energy* - comes from matter naturally assimilated by the body in the metabolic process;
2. *Matter* - energy will convert matter, however, in order for there to be something to convert, it is necessary that the matter is in the field of action of the energy, that is, within the body of the converting agent. Energy cannot convert matter beyond its own body extension, where it acts;
3. *Sensory data of phenomena* - phenomena is all that - characteristics, properties, effects - that is perceptible to one of the five senses. Matter is converted by energy based on this data. For a phenomenon to be reproduced in the acquired matter, it is necessary that, in addition to the converting energy and the matter to be converted, it must have the sensory data of the phenomenon it wishes to replicate, or the data necessary to generate an unprecedented phenomenon, which is nothing more than the mixture of various phenomena.
4. *Experience* - the more experience a converting agent has in managing these three conditions, the better the "magic" will be performed, for lack of a better name.

**RESTRICTIONS**

1. Energy can only convert matter that is within the body extension of the converter agent;
2. Phenomena can be created, but only based on phenomena already stored in the sensory database;
3. After conversion, the body must expel the converted matter. The matter that reproduces/generates the phenomenon can only be expelled by the same means by which it is ingested: it is not immediately teleported out of the body, therefore, the exit is a delicate and organized process that, if performed incorrectly or speedily can damage the organism of the user. Each species has different physiologies in relation to how they ingest this matter.
4. After being expelled, that converted portion of matter will only remain under the control of the converting agent - which allows it to change its shape and volume, not being able to change its mass or nature - if it is established as a body extension. That is, if it receives organic properties and remains energetically fed by the body. If that connection breaks, the same will happen as in the case of a severed arm: the agent simply loses control over that piece of matter.

**Sorry for my bad english, but i really wanted your opinion on this system.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You describe metabolism - the breaking down of food molecules and use of the breakdown products for energy and the maintenance of the organism.**

1. *Energy* - comes from *food* naturally assimilated by the body in the metabolic process;
2. *Matter* - *the body can use* energy *to metabolize* matter, however, *you have got to eat the matter first.*
3. *Sensory data of phenomena* - phenomena is all that - characteristics, properties, effects - that is perceptible to one of the five senses. *Metabolic needs of the body* are based on this data.

**RESTRICTIONS**

1. Energy can only convert matter that *has been eaten*.
2. *Biological molecules and body parts* can be created, but only based on phenomena already stored in the sensory database;
3. After conversion, the body must *poop and pee* the converted matter... the exit is a delicate and organized process that, if performed incorrectly or speedily can damage the organism of the user. *so true!*
4. that converted portion of matter will only remain under the control of the converting agent - *if it is anabolically converted to biomolecules and added to the body*. That is, if it receives organic properties and remains energetically fed by the body. If that connection breaks, the same will happen as in the case of a severed arm: the agent simply loses control over that piece of matter.

---

What you describe so mirrors the processes of anabolism / catabolism that I think biology must have been your inspiration.  Which is good, because biology makes sense and additional ramifications of your magic system can also be derived from biology.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your comment!  I would like to ask a few questions:
   1. Not that this is biologically possible, but would you find it interesting if the converted matter could be expelled like sweat, or regurgitated by the mouth, like vomiting?
   2. Regarding a name for this system in general, would you have any suggestions for words related to the topic that you could suggest to me?  I didn't want to keep calling it "magic".

Comment: @Konawe - you could use keep the concept of metabolism but use the original Greek "Metabolismos".  You could keep anabolism and catabolism (or katabolism) for building up or breaking down.  As regards expelling waste from the body that can happen however works for your store.

Comment: thanks for the support!